# How to execute my own command installed with rpm

Tags: fedora, rpm

I made a package using rpm in Fedora 29. These are the steps I followed:

1. `# dnf install fedora-packager fedora-review`
2. `# usermod -a -G mock my_user` Added my user to mock group
3. `$ rpmdev-setuptree` Then set up the necesary directory tree to generate the package
4. `nano rpmbuild/SPECS/paquete.specs`

Lastly I created the .spec file and wrote this inside:

[image]

So when I install the package, it is supposed to install a command named "hola" that when it's called prints the message writen in the `echo` of the `%build` section, right?

To install the package I followed these steps:

1. `$ rpmbuild -ba paquete.spec` Built the package with `+exit 0` so everything went OK.
2. `$ sudo rpm -ivh paquete-1-1.x86_64.rpm` Install the package with rpm
3. `$ rpm -qi paquete` This shows the info of the package without any issue.

So I think I installed the package with success, but I want to run my command "`hola`" just as a `nano` or a `gcc` command without using "`./`" to execute it... What am I missing?

Comment: Your `PATH` variable does not include the directory your `hola` executable resides in.

Comment: Please show the .spec file **as text** instead of an image. You install your program `hola` as `/usr/bin/hello-world.sh`, so you should run `hello-world.sh` instead of `hola`.

Comment: @Bodo Thanks, now I understand. What should I change in my .spec file to run just `hola` instead?

Comment: Please copy&paste the .spec file **as text** to the question. This would allow to copy it to the answer and modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You install your program `hola` as `/usr/bin/hello-world.sh`, so you should run `hello-world.sh` instead of `hola`.

Or change your `.spec` file to install the program as `/usr/bin/hola` instead of `/usr/bin/hello-world.sh`.